# Print messages from a bot on Telegram in the console

Tags: python, telegram

Is there a way that with Python I can print the messages that a bot sends me in the console and then perform an action?

I already tried several things, but the most I managed was to print the messages that I myself sent to the bot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple echo bot that *Simulating Incoming Messages* in Python that interacts with the Telegram Bot API. The bot prints user input and performs various behaviors. Please note that you can use other libraries or approaches to achieve the same result.

```
import requests

# Define your bot token
TOKEN = 'your_bot_token'
BASE_URL = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}'

# Function to send a message to the bot
def send_message(chat_id, text):
    url = f'{BASE_URL}/sendMessage'
    params = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text}
    response = requests.post(url, params=params)
    return response.json()

# Function to handle incoming messages
def handle_messages(update):
    user_input = update['message']['text']
    chat_id = update['message']['chat']['id']

    print(f'User: {user_input}')

    # Process the user input and generate a response
    bot_response = generate_bot_response(user_input)

    # Send the bot's response back to the user
    send_message(chat_id, f'Bot: {bot_response}')

    # Perform your desired action based on the bot's response
    perform_action(bot_response)

# Function to generate a bot response (you need to implement this)
def generate_bot_response(user_input):
    # Implement your logic to generate a response based on user input
    # For simplicity, let's just echo the user's input in this example.
    return f'You said: {user_input}'

# Function to perform an action based on the bot's response
def perform_action(bot_response):
    # Implement your logic to perform an action based on the bot's response
    # For simplicity, let's just print the bot's response in this example.
    print(f'Action: {bot_response}')
    if bot_response == '':
        pass
    elif bot_response == ' ':
        pass
    else:
        pass

# Example usage
while True:
    user_input = input("You: ")
    if user_input.lower() == 'exit':
        break

    # Simulate an incoming message
    handle_messages({'message': {'text': user_input, 'chat': {'id': 123456789}}})
```